# Computational cost

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Is there someone that knows what the computational cost for this two pieces of code is?

```c
while (n > 2)
   n = sqrt(n);

while (n > 2)
   n = log(n);
```

Comment: No, it's just my curiosity ( i see the question in a forum and i became curios). :)

Comment: It rather depends what the representation of n is - for arbitrary precision, sqrt(n) is itself O(log n)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second would be `O(log* n)` where `log *` is the [iterated logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm).

Analysing the first one yields something like this:

```
sqrt(n) = n ^ (1/2)
sqrt(sqrt(n)) = n ^ (1/4)
sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(n))) = n ^ (1/8)
...
sqrt applied k times = n ^ (1/2^k)
```

Consider that the first algorithm executes `k` times (basically, the number of times we have to apply `sqrt` until `n <= 2`).

Consider this reasoning:

```
n ^ (1/2^k) = p (p <= 2) | ^ (2^k)
n = p ^ (2^k) | log
log n = (2^k) log p | log
log log n = log (2 ^ k) + log log p
log log n = klog2 + log log p
=> k ~= log log n
```

So the first algorithm is `O(log log n)`.

Comment: I also thought the same thing(something like log2(log2(n)) but I was not sure, for the second?

Comment: @BlackShadow - simply use these formulas: `1. sqrt(n) = n ^ (1/2); 2. (a^b)^c = a^(b*c); 3. log (a*b) = log a + log b; 4. log (a^b) = b*log a`. This is all you need to prove it.

Comment: I guess you used also properites of big-O to remove "1/log 2" and "log log p / log 2".

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the first one should become obvious if one recasts it in the log domain:

```
n = log2(n);
while (n > 1)
    n = n / 2;
```

How many times do you need to halve a number in order to reach 1?  O(log n).